# Making my own gamepad Driver?

Tags: windows-7, driver

I am trying to find out how I should go about making my own gamepad compatible with windows based games. I have used some time to read up on windows drivers but I feel kind of lost and unsure about how I should solve my problem. What i am asking for is some guidance toward what kind of solution or approach I should take.

So I have made a Arduino based GamePad which communicates with the computer over serialport(usb). From here I assume I need to make a driver which identifies itself as a GamePad(Device driver, Plug and Play driver)? I am not sure if I am done at this point or if I have to be compatible with DirectInput somehow?

-Michael

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple slider with RS232 and C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616000/simple-slider-with-rs232-and-c-sharp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Forum thread about arduino and ppJoy virtual joystick.
http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1210699098